# Navigate via back-button from child fragment back to parent activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment-backstack

I have a main activity and 2 fragments. In my main activity I have navigation drawer that navigates through the fragments. I handle the back button pressed like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

After navigating between the two fragments, when I hit the back button, I get last fragment from backstack. However, navigating from fragment to another fragment should not be possible.

**More Clarity:**

I have one Activity (with a navigation drawer) and 2 Fragments. From the navigation drawer I can go to both fragments as many times as I want. But when I hit the back button, I want always to go back to the `main_activity.xml`.

Comment: *what I want to do is return to my man activity from any fragment at all times.*, if you are not starting a new Activity, you are always on your `MainActivity`

Comment: @Blackbelt Sorry, what I meant was to return to `main_activity.xml`. Edited the question

Comment: So...you only have one activity. And you want to return to this activity, which you are still on. Doesn't make sense to me :( You ARE still in the main_activity.xml. If you want to get the same let's say 'state' as in the beginning, call your activity from the fragments to do that.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re See the updated question. I hope thats more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate through Activities, the best way is to use `Intent`s like this (if I understood your question):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have 1 Activity (with a navigation drawer) and 2 Fragments. From the navigation drawer I can go to both fragments as many times as I want. But when I hit the back button, I want to go back to the `main_activity.xml` instead popping from the stack

Comment: try to create one more fragment which is the Home fragment and put there everything you have on the main_activity.xml and you can go back to it from the navigation drawer. I think that when you have Fragments in an activity, you can not have layouts outside them

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response. Helped me come up with a solution. +1 and accepted

Comment: @Alias could you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
**OnCreate() :-**


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_category_feed_list, null);

        RelativeLayout rrBack = (RelativeLayout) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.rr_back);
        TextView title = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        title.setText("");
        title.setTypeface(typeFaceMedium);
        rrBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory("" + userUsername).setAction("On Search Feed Screen").setLabel("Pressed Back Button").build());
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

**actionbar_category_feed_list.xml**

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rr_back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/back_red" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.converza.library.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rr_back"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>



**At last in your fragment Activity use a OnactivityResult() for get a Returnintent from Activity.**

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Const.FEEDDETAIL && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e(tag, "DatashBoard Const.FEEDDETAIL RESULT_OK");
        } else if (requestCode == Const.FEEDDETAIL && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e(tag, "DatashBoard Const.FEEDDETAIL RESULT_CANCELED");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the fragment by tag and check if it is null or not, if it is null then replace that fragment or show the fragment again if fragment is hidden.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
             Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Tag");

        if (fr == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        new Main_Fragment(), "Fragment_Tag").commit();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
}
```

Comment: where is your finish coming from

Comment: you can put super.onBackPressed(); instead of finish();. And finish(); is the part of Activity.